# Enable tsconfig.json to compileOnSave for .js files

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, typescript, tsconfig

I am using Visual Studio Professional 2015 Update 3, and TypeScript 2.8.4.  I have a simple project with

```
Scripts/
└── Widgets/
    ├── main.ts
    └── tsconfig.json
```

In `main.ts`:

```js
console.log("Hello, world!");
```

In `tsconfig.json`

```js
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "outFile": "dist/widgets.js"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

The `compileOnSave` settings works just fine like this.  However, when I change `main.ts` to `main.js` it doesn't compile on save, despite the `allowJs` setting being set.  Is there something I can do to have `compileOnSave` work for files with extension `.js`?

Comment: what are you expecting it to compile when you save main.js?

Comment: @paul, I was expecting it to compile the same thing as when I manually build the project with Visual Studio, i.e., the `console.log` statement and a comment for the source map.

Comment: Sourcemaps map typescript to compiled javascript. In your example, I think, there is nothing to compile (no typescript) so no need for a sourcemap

Comment: @paul, you may have misunderstood my question?  The compiler seems to be working fine.  It's the `compileOnSave` that's not working for `.js` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible in Visual Studio 2015.  It should work in Visual Studio 2017.

See [https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14536](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14536#issuecomment-285416036).